# C# can't convert Hex to readable string

Tags: c#, character-encoding, hex

I'm trying to decode a hex string to readable string but every time I try it outputs an unreadable string.

First I pass the hex `"2 41 4e 56 0 0 30 30 30 30 30 34 36 56 56 49 3 21"` and I convert it to `byte[]` with this:

```
    byte[] bb = Enumerable.Range(0, Hex.Length)
         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(Hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
         .ToArray();
```

Then I try to convert it to a readable string with this:

```
result = Encoding.Default.GetString(bb);
```

I get an unreadable string:

> $�`Ceed�!

.Default or .Unicode, both output something different than I expect.

If I use [this tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) (set to Unicode) it outputs what I expect which is:

> ANV0000046VVI!

So I know it somehow should work.

I don't know what else to do. I thought that would be enough but not...

Comment: Your expected output string (`ANV0000046VVI!`) is entirely made up of ASCII characters, so everything should be in the range `0x20-0x7e`.  What encoding do you expect to see.  If it's UTF-16, then every second byte should be zero. If it's UTF-8, then you might see a BOM at the start (it's not there), and otherwise characters in the ASCII range.  Your hex numbers include two consecutive zeros, as well as a two at the front and a three near the end.  I have no idea about your tool.  It lists "Unicode" as well as UTF-8, UTF-16 (LE) and UTF-16 (BE),  All of those give different results ???

Comment: Where are you getting this hex string from?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can *filter out* command characters (`0x02`, `0x00`, `0x03`) and get required outcome:

```
  string source = "2 41 4e 56 0 0 30 30 30 30 30 34 36 56 56 49 3 21";

  string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(source
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(item => byte.Parse(item, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
    .Where(item => item >= ' ')
    .ToArray());

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  ANV0000046VVI!
```

Now the next question appears: why are all these command characters within the `source`?

Comment: Thaaaaank youuuu !! Thats exactly what I needed!!